# <br /> tag and spaces

Tags: html

Just a quick question that's nagged at me for a while. When using the `<br />` tag, is the tag considered to be a space between text as well? 
In other words, if the html was: `<p>Publication Author<br />Publication Citation</p>`, would it be read as "Publication Author Publication Citation" or "Publication AuthorPublication Citation"?

Comment: Read by who????

Comment: Both by crawlers and screen readers.

Answer (score 5):

At the technical reading-the-specs level, the first one is correct. In HTML, the `br` tag is [white space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1) and functions as a separator.

In terms of actual practice, however, it should be interpreted as, literally

```
Publication Author
Publication Citation
```

which in terms of "reading" carries a different sort of "pause" from simply two words separated by a space.

As for screenreaders, now that you've specified, things get more complicated as they're highly configurable to the user's preference. I don't do any work with them, but I've seen various comments over time that one ignores them, another respects them with a slighly longer than between-words pause as I mentioned above but could also be told to ignore them, etc. It's a specialized area, and if you need definite answers you might pose the question in the Accessify forum or similar and report back. Screenreaders in general just [haven't come up](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=screenreaders) much on this site